# How to save frequently used values without going through the database every time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am building a questionnaire, and i want to save the number of questions the user has completed and the number of questions available. I know how to calculate these values, but I don't want to run through the database, every time the user asks for a page that shows this information (which is quite often).

I considered saving it in the Session, but the problem is that the Session expires before the Authentication, so the information might get lost, but the user will still be logged in.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that i am working on a server, where i cannot specify the session timeout myself. Also, the number of answered questions has to be updated, when a user answers a question.

Comment: tha Cache class works independently of the session timeout - see the links in my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

session's generally are extended each time a request is made to the server, so while someone is using the questionnaire, periodically send a request to the server using JavaScript just to ensure the session isn't ended.

Answer (score 0):

A very interesing resource about caching and ASP.NET is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg650661.aspx

As you can't specify the session timeout use the [`Cache` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) - it supports several different mechanisms for when to discard the cached item...

EDIT - as per comment:

With a cache you should implement a "write-through"-scheme - i.e. always update both, the cache and the DB which means the Cache is always right and any read never hits the DB after the initial load on application startup.

Another option is to update the DB and invalidate the cache item... on next read access you get a "cache miss" and handle that by hitting the DB and saving the result into the Cache... this way you hit the DB for reads in worstcase as often as for writes... this pattern only helps if you have much more reads than writes...

Comment: When the answered question count is updated (the user has answered a new question), the cache is not valid anymore. How would you update it?

Comment: @Kenci as with every cache you should implement a "write-through"-scheme (i.e. always update both, the cache and the DB).

Comment: @Kenci another option is to just invalidate the cached value on update and on next read access check the chace (if it is not in there just load it into the cache) etc.

Comment: I like your answer and your effort! I am not saving the number of questions answered in the database, but calculating it by going through each question, to see if all answer possibilities have been answered, then summing it all up. Because i have a lot of questions and answer possibilities, this would would be alot of calls to the database, which is AFAICS what a write-through scheme would require. I want to get the number once, when the user logs in, and then update it in the memory. I think i will go with @Kae Verens answer, but thanks for the help. And correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider increasing the session timeout.